# Is a full clone the only way to submodule add a branch?

Tags: git

I want to add a submodule that references a specific (non-master) branch.  The following will only grab the master branch due to `--depth=1`, so the command will inevitably fail;

```
git submodule add -b myBranch --depth=1 git@host.com:some/large/repo
```

Because `submodule add` doesn't support `--single-branch`, does this mean my only option is to clone the entire repo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation of `git-clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---depthltdepthgt):

> **--depth** *depth*
>
> Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified
>   number of commits. **Implies `--single-branch` unless `--no-single-branch`
>   is given to fetch the histories near the tips of all branches.**
>
> **--[no-]single-branch**
>
> Clone only the history leading to the tip of a single branch,
>   either specified by the `--branch` option or the primary branch
>   remote’s HEAD points at. **When creating a shallow clone with the
>   --depth option, this is the default**, unless `--no-single-branch` 
>   is given to fetch the histories near the tips of all branches.
>   Further fetches into the resulting repository will only update the
>   remote-tracking branch for the branch this option was used for the
>   initial cloning. If the HEAD at the remote did not point at any 
>   branch when `--single-branch` clone was made, no remote-tracking
>   branch is created.

Thus, if `git submodule add` performs the cloning with `git clone`, then in your use case `--single-branch` is implied. However, it will work correctly only if `git submodule add` forwards the `-b` option to `git clone`.

A guaranteed way of achieving the desired result (without making any assumptions about inner workings of `git submodule add`) is to `git clone` the submodule repository on your own using the options of your choice and then add the existing directory as a submodule:

```
git clone -b myBranch --single-branch --depth=1 git@host.com:some/large/repo large_repo
git submodule add -b myBranch git@host.com:some/large/repo large_repo
```

> **git submodule add** *options* *repository* [*path*]
>
> ...
>
> *path* is the relative location for the cloned submodule to exist in the
>   superproject. If *path* does not exist, then the submodule is created by
>   cloning from the named URL. **If** *path* **does exist and is already a valid
>   Git repository, then this is added to the changeset without cloning**.

Comment: The first part of your answer is irrelevant because `git submodule add` does not support `--single-branch` as noted in the question.  However, the second part looks legit.

Comment: @StaffordWilliams I didn't argue that `git submodule add` supports `--single-branch`. My point was that `git submodule add -b myBranch --depth 1` calls `git clone -b myBranch --depth 1`, and the latter would imply `--single-branch`.

Comment: I think you're saying you feel like `--single-branch` should exist on `submodule add`, due to the presence of `submodule add --depth`, even though it doesn't?

Comment: @StaffordWilliams No, I am saying that `git submodule add` delegates some of its work to `git clone`, so if it passes the `-b` and `--depth` options to `git clone`, then cloning would be performed in `--single-branch` mode implicitly. But, if you have doubts, go with the safer 2nd method (that's why I included it in my answer).

Comment: So I should be able to use `--single-branch` with `submodule add`?

Comment: @StaffordWilliams I don't think so, but you can try.

Comment: Second part worked (thanks!), but the commands are slightly different.  Do you wanna update your commands so I can mark this as the answer?  Commands are; `git clone -b myBranch --single-branch --depth=1 git@host.com:some/large/repo large_repo` and `git submodule add -b myBranch git@host.com:some/large/repo large_repo`

Comment: @StaffordWilliams Updated

Comment: Not sure the second way works, at least the way I was expecting.  Set things up that way, but `git pull --recurse-submodules` from the top level pulled in all the other branches in the submodule, even though it was explicitly cloned --single-branch --depth 1 and the top level repo. was told which branch to track.

Comment: this didn't work for me... it seems it still download large files from other branches. They appear to be stored in .git\modules\module-name\objects\pack