# git add submodule of only a certain branch

Tags: git, branch, git-submodules

Is it possible to only checkout a single branch as a submodule WITHOUT the overhead of the whole repository in my main repositories working directory? (And really only download the files of that branch)

I think of having a submodule for a javascript library with a branch called "dist" containing only the minified compiled ready-to-use js file. The "master" would instead contain the source files and a bunch of other stuff only needed for development of the lib.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git submodules: Specify a branch/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854/git-submodules-specify-a-branch-tag)

Comment: I have edited my answer, but the key is: you will checkout the branch you want, however, you still need tob  fetch the all repo.

Comment: Although, there is a single branch option: see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Note that a submodule only represents a fixed SHA1.

That being said, on git submodule update --remote, you can make a submodule change its SHA1 by the latest of a given branch by following my answer "[git submodule tracking latest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309)"

For an existing submodule:

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<path>.branch <branch>
```

A repo can add itself as a submodule, with a given branch.
I used to do so for the [`gh-pages` of a GitHub pages repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40967706/6309).

Since a submodule is a sub-repo, you will download the repo, and only checkout the branch you need.
Although, there is [a `--single-branch` option to `git clone`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14930421/6309) which does limit the clone to a single branch.
You can try and add again your submodule with the `-b` (`git submodule add -b abranch`) option to check that is did clone the remote submodule repo with only that one branch in it.
See "[Is a full clone the only way to submodule add a branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38091173/6309)".

Answer (score 0):

Adding **Submodule Branch(Submodule1Branch)** inside **MainProjectBranch** In Same **Repository** Process :-

> Create Branch of Submodule(treated as Repository):-

- Create 1 Branch as **Submodule1Branch**  from **Master**.
- Clone **Submodule1Branch** in your  local machine and delete everything of Master in it and push with respective Project of **Submodule1Branch** only by given commands:-

  - git clone -b Submodule1Branch
    https://Your@bitbucket.com/yourmasterporject.git
  - git status
  - git add .
  - git commit -m “Deleted everything of Master Project and loaded with my submodule project data“
  - git push

> Add this Submodule1Branch as a Submodule of your  MainProjectBranch in same repo:-

- Create a branch from “Master” and give name it “ MainProjectBranch”.
- Clone this branch in you local.
- Now Perform Submodule on this branch by given commands:-
- git submodule add -b Submodule1Branch https://Your@bitbucket.com/yourmasterporject.git
  Submodules/
- git status
- cat .gitmodules
- git add .
- git commit -m "Added **Submodule1Branch** As Submodule of **MainProjectBranch**."
- git push

**Result :-**  You may go one bitbucket or git server and check  **MainProjectBranch** there you will find  **Submodule1Branch** as submodule of **MainProjectBranch**.

> Note:- You can perform same above steps for separate repositories as
>   well .(Ex:- submodule repo will be different and main project repo
>   will be different). Happy coding!! :).